# MongoDB C# filter datetime stored as a string

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm trying to create a filter and find records by a date range. The thing is, the dates in our mongo server are (sadly, its historically like this and was imported from another database) stored as string type, in the format of "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss". How can I filter from user input dates? No matter what I've tried I got wrong results.

Here's some code:

```
[Serializable]
public class Error
{
    [BsonElement("projectName")]
    public string projectName { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("programName")]
    public string programName { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("errorDescription")]
    public string errorDescription { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("userDescription")]
    public string userDescription { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("logDateTime")]
    [BsonSerializer(typeof(DateSerializer))]
    public DateTime logDateTime { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("writeDateTime")]
    public string writeDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

And here's the DateSerializer:

```
public class DateSerializer: SerializerBase<DateTime>
{
    public override void Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, DateTime value)
    {
        context.Writer.WriteString(value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    }

    public override DateTime Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
    {
        var dateText = context.Reader.ReadString();
        return convertToDate(dateText);
    }

    private DateTime convertToDate(string dateText)
    {
        CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);
        ci.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd'/'MM'/'yyyy";
        ci.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern = "hh':'mm tt";
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;

        string format = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"; 
        DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateText, format, ci);
        return dateTime;
    }
}
```

on my filter:

```
DateTime dateTime2 = DateTime.ParseExact(date, format, ci);
var fromDateFilter = builder.Gte(x => x.error.logDateTime, dateTime2);
```

and eventually:

```
filter = filter & fromDateFilter;
var results = errorCollection.Find(filter).ToList();
```

I've tried many different ways but can't seem to get the comparison to work properly.

**Edit**: I only care about the dates. The time is not very important.

**Edit 2** - Apparently it only compares the day, for example it returns that 01/06/2017 (dd/mm/yyyy) is smaller than 06/02/2017 (dd/mm/yyyy). This is also true for 02-05/06/2017 until 06/06/2017.

Comment: In the `DateSerializer.Serialize` method, why to use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`, not "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"?

Comment: tried that...doesn't work for me. I still get wrong results.

Comment: x.error.logDateTime, shouln't it be x.logDateTime ?

Comment: No, because there is another wrapping class:

    public class ErrorInfo
    {
        [BsonId]
        public ObjectId id { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("error")]
        public Error error { get; set; }
    }
and the builder is defined as 

var builder = Builders<ErrorInfo>.Filter;